# Multiple integration problem with exp

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Show that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-x^2)\, dx = \sqrt{\pi}$.

I believe it is necessary to use the Fubini's Theorem and the Change of Variables Theorem. 
I guess the variable shift function can be $g: (s,v)\times (s,2\pi) \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$, such that $g(r,\theta)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$.

I've seen this question here, but none explains why g fits the assumptions of the theorem. As, for example, why $g$ is a diffeomorphism of class $C^1$, or why $g((s,v)\times (s,2\pi))$ is compact and $J$-measurable.

PS.: I know that Change of Variables Theorem It has other versions with different hypotheses, but these are the book I follow.

Comment: [Several proofs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral).

Comment: @Lucian I dont know that problem It was one of the "classics". Thank you.

Comment: Let the domain of your change of variable function $g$ be a compact interval of the form $[r,R]\times [\epsilon,2\pi]$, where $\epsilon,r$ are small and positive, and $R\to\infty$. The restriction of $g$ to that compact set is injective, and no problems arise. Actually, if you use the domain $[0,R]\times[0,2\pi]$ the non-injectivity only happens in a Jordan null set, and can thus be ignored.

Comment: @LetDC, I'm a bit busy now, sorry. I'm glad that good people already showed up. If I understood the question right, the problem is not with the computation, but why the theorem applies. Jyrki's comment already explains it.. (it could be converted into an answer, IMO)

Comment: @IvoTerek Yes, the other comments helped me. But thank you, and good luck in their occupations.

Answer (score 0):

Identify it as the square root of the product of 2 integrals which can be combined into a double integral of $exp[-(x^2+y^2)]$.  Then switch to polar coordinates to evaluate.  That's how Gauss did it (I think).